# Bind a variable based on the value of another variable. C# and Nancy

Tags: c#, nancy

I'm using Nancy with my C# on a web API and would like to do something like this:

```
string str = "ThirdPartyContract";
ThirdPartyContract contract = this.Bind<str>();
```

The main reason is have a lot of different types to Bind and would like to avoid making a POST for each type. So sending a variable which tells me what to Bind and then doing it is what I try to achieve.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to post several different unrelated types of data to the same URL, and dynamically figure out how which type to bind to?  I think you can clarify your question by providing a couple of examples of input, and roughly what your think the code to handle them should be.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to pass the contract type as a query parameter, something like this:

```
string contractType = this.Request.Query["type"];
if (contractType == "ThirdPartyContract") {
    var contract = this.Bind<ThirdPartyContract>();
    // ...
} else if (contractType == "OtherContract") {
    var contract = this.Bind<OtherContract>();
    // ...
} else {
   // handle the unknown contract case
}
```